# Android sort ArrayLit<class> in API16?

Tags: java, android, sorting, arraylist

I´m doing an assignment and it´s required to support API16.

My view is a custom ArrayListAdapter with takes an

```
ArrayList<someclass>
```

The problem is that I want to make it possible to sort the data the user has put in the list.

```
items.sort(new Comparator<someclass>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(someclass item1, someclass item2) {
        return item1.Name.compareTo(item2.Name);
    }
});
```

But when I try Android Studio tells that I need API 24.

how do I sort the list in API 16?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use `Collections.sort`

```
Collections.sort(items, new Comparator<someclass>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(someclass item1, someclass item2) {
        return item1.Name.compareTo(item2.Name);
    }
});
```